# Why does my batch script fails randomly with The System Cannot Find The File Specified?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So, I have this script running in order to continuely ping a server, and log the ping result with the current date into a file.

Its pretty simple

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
:Pinging
ping 192.168.0.78 -n 1 -w 20 > C:\ping.txt
set T=
for /f "Delims=" %%x in (C:\ping.txt) do set T=!T! %%x
echo %T%
echo %date%-%time% %T% >> C:\PingResult.log
goto Pinging
```

The problem is, this sometimes works, sometimes it gives a "**The System Cannot Find The File Specified**" error

The script doesn't stop or exit, it just keeps running as intended. Is there something am I doing wrong?

I have already tried another file paths, running with and without admin privileges, always the same random error.

Comment: I got same error while writing to file too quickly. I supposed that antivirus was blocking write operations. If you have running antivirus add **PingResult.log** to exception list and move it to any subfolder. Because user don't have right to modify system disk's root files usually.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do it like this instead?

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:Pinging
Set "_=."
(For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 192.168.0.78 -n 1 -w
 20') Do If Not Defined _ (Set "Prompt=$S%%G"
        %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K 0<NUL) Else (
        Set /P "=!DATE!-!TIME! %%G" 0<NUL
        Set "_=")) 1>>"C:\PingResult.log"
GoTo Pinging
```